# javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

I'm havin an Auction.java class and since I've added a new type of Bid(the Ducth one) and made an abstract class Bid.java--@Entity @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)(EnglishBid and DucthBid extend Abstract Bid class and have their own methos isHighter/isLower) I get this ERROR(when I want to add a NEW Auction(using JSF at front-end) and save into DB using EntityManager):

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
```

this is Auction.java(@Named, @ViewScoped) :

```
private AbstractBid highestBid; //One to One  RELATIONSHIP + CASCADE=ALL

private List<AbstractBid> bids = new ArrayList<AbstractBid>();


@OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "auction")
@Column(nullable = true, updatable = false)
@OrderBy("amount DESC")
public List<AbstractBid> getBids() {
    return bids;
}

public void setBids(List<AbstractBid> bids) {
    this.bids = bids;
}

public void addBid(AbstractBid bid) {

    if(bid instanceof EnglishBid)
    {

        if (!((EnglishBid) bid).isHigher(originalPrice)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The new bid ("
                    + ((EnglishBid) bid).getAmount()
                    + ") have to be greater than original price ("
                    + originalPrice + ")");
        }

        if (!((EnglishBid) bid).isHigher((EnglishBid) highestBid)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The new bid ("
                    + ((EnglishBid) bid).getAmount()
                    + ") have to be greater than original price ("
                    + ((EnglishBid) highestBid).getAmount() + ")");
        }

        this.getBids().add(bid);
        this.setHighestBid(bid);
    }

    else

        if(bid instanceof DutchBid)
        {

            if (!((DutchBid) bid).isLower(originalPrice)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The new bid ("
                        + ((DutchBid) bid).getAmount()
                        + ") have to be lower than original price ("
                        + originalPrice + ")");
            }

            if (!((DutchBid) bid).isLower((DutchBid) highestBid)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The new bid ("
                        + ((DutchBid) bid).getAmount()
                        + ") have to be lower than hightestBid ("
                        + ((DutchBid) highestBid).getAmount() + ")");
            }

            this.getBids().add(bid);
            this.setHighestBid(bid);
        }
}
```

and AbstractBid.java:

```
public AbstractBid(User bidder, Auction auction, Long amount) {
    this.bidder = bidder;
    this.auction = auction;
    this.amount = amount;

    auction.addBid(this);
}
```

both classes implement Serializable and have @Id @GeneratedValue.

Anyone any ideea ?